# Unable to record multiple protocols in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, protocols, recording

I have application which has multiple protocols ex. HTTP, SMTP,FTP, When i am trying to Record this application for load testing using JMeter, JMeter captured HTTP requests only, not FTP, SMTP, JMeter does not record multiple protocols?
is there any workaround to add all protocols in load testing, 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now ([JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)) JMeter is capable of capturing only HTTP or HTTPS traffic via its [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) (and actually it's reflected in its name)

Given the nature of the FTP and SMTP protocols it's better to mimic the required load using [FTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#FTP_Request) and [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) correspondingly.

---

If you have to do the recording you can consider capturing the underlying [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) traffic using low-level sniffing tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and replay it with [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) or [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler but it is even more complex than going for manual creation of the FTP and SMTP requests as you will have to deal with "raw" TCP traffic which is not that pretty and human-readable.

Alternatively you can consider LoadRunner which is theoretically [capable of recording](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/101200_c_vuser_types.htm) both FTP and SMTP protocols and free for up to 50 virtual users

Comment: Thanks so much all , I will go for manual creation of the FTP and SMTP, JMeter is client requirement so i cant go with Load Runner